# Sagemaker Studio - limit number of kernels per user

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

How to limit the number of kernels which a single user can run simultaneously in Sagemaker Studio?

I'm looking for something similar to:

```
"Action": "sagemaker:CreateApp",
        "Resource": "*",
        "Condition": {
            "ForAllValues:StringLike": {
                "sagemaker:InstanceTypes": [
                    "ml.c5.*"
             }
         }
```

but limiting instance count available for a single studio user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its **not possibile** through IAM. There is no condition in sagemaker's IAM policies for kernel count. You can check available condition keys for sagemaker [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazonsagemaker.html#amazonsagemaker-policy-keys).

You would have to develop a fully custom solution for monitoring user activities in sagemaker, and taking corrective actions based on your own criteria.